# Запятая на стыке союзов?

Tags: запятые

Но идет накопление негатива, и если эта энергия высвободится, она может оказаться очень мощной и даже деструктивной".

Возможна ли запятая после *и*?

по аналогии с тем, что у Розенталя:

А женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, хотя слова ее были привычными, у Сабурова от них вдруг защемило сердце (Симонов) (при изъятии придаточного уступительного с союзом хотя предложно-местоименное сочетание от них становится неясным, но в структурном отношении такое изъятие возможно, поэтому запятая между сочинительным и подчинительным союзами в подобных случаях обычно ставится).

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что запятую после союза "и" ставить не надо.

Решение о постановке запятой  на стыке двух союзов зависит от возможности  разделить придаточное предложение на главную и придаточную часть. Если это сделать невозможно или нежелательно, то СПП в составе сложной конструкции рассматривается как единое целое(запятая  на стыке союзов не ставится).

Хотя в данном случае структурная перестановка возможна, но она нарушает семантические связи в предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что запятая просто невозможна, ни по каким мотивам.
Тут вот какое дело. Запятая после и обозначала бы обособление придаточного как если бы оно начиналось с "если". Но такоя понимание структуры фразы невозможно, ибо изъятие придаточного в таком составе приводит к бессмыслице (ключевое слово в понимании - "энергия"): "Но идет накопление негатива, и она может оказаться очень мощной и даже деструктивной". Совершенно непонятно, о чем речь: даже если пренебречь грамматическим родом местоимения, о том, кто окажется "мощным и деструктивным", в первой части ничего не говорится. Так что я бы не сказал, что "такое изъятие" так уж допустимо даже только "в структурном отношении".

В примере же из Розенталя такая ситуация не возникает. По смыслу у Сабурова от них защемило сердце - это "от её слов". Если уберем придаточное "и хотя слова...", получится "от несчастий". Осмыслено - и почти тот же смысл. Так что у Симонова запятая оправдана.